# How to reset ipywidgets with multithreading?

Tags: ipython, python-multithreading, ipywidgets

Using Google Colab, I'm trying to create an interactive widget that will let me selection a position in an audio file, and then simultaneously play it back AND plot the waveform at the same time. I'm almost there, thanks to countless examples of bits of the problem. However, I'm stuck with the following: The first time this runs, it works as expected - it plays the audio and animates the waveform (YAY!). What doesn't work is when I adjust the start slider. What I want it to do is to clear the graph and start plotting the new waveform. It doesn't. It does play the audio at the new start time though. So, clearly, I'm close. But what can I do? I think it has something to do with the multithreading join, but if I don't join it, then it doesn't even animate the initial set up.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from IPython.display import Audio, display
from ipywidgets import interactive,  widgets

import threading
import time

from PIL import Image
from io import StringIO

def note(frequency, length, amplitude=1, sample_rate=44100):
    time_points = np.linspace(0, length, length*sample_rate)
    data = np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*time_points)
    data = amplitude*data
    return data

song_rate = 22050
song_amp =  np.concatenate(
             (note(440.00, 1, 1.0, song_rate),  #A 
              note(493.88, 1, 0.9, song_rate),  #B 
              note(523.25, 1, 0.8, song_rate),  #C
              note(587.33, 1, 0.7, song_rate),  #D 
              note(659.25, 1, 0.6, song_rate),  #E
              note(698.46, 1, 0.5, song_rate),  #F
              note(783.99, 1, 0.4, song_rate),  #G
              ),             
             axis=-1)

animation_frames_per_secs = 1

mygraph = display(display_id=True)
mythread = None

def animate_images(start_secs, width_secs, duration_secs):
    for tick in range(duration_secs*animation_frames_per_secs):
      curr_time = start_secs + (tick*1.0/animation_frames_per_secs)
      make_image(curr_time, width_secs)
      time.sleep(1.0/animation_frames_per_secs)

def make_image(current_time, time_window):
    global song_amp, song_rate, mythread, mygraph  
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 2))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    x = np.arange(int(current_time*song_rate),
                      int((current_time+time_window)*song_rate),
                      1)/song_rate
    y = song_amp[int(current_time*song_rate):int((current_time+time_window)*song_rate)]
    ax1.plot(x,y)
    buffer = StringIO()
    canvas = plt.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
    canvas.draw()
    image = Image.frombytes('RGB', canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
    plt.close()
    mygraph.update(image)

def play_music(start_secs=0, width_secs=3.0/440, duration_secs=2):
    global song_amp, song_rate, mythread, mygraph
    s = song_amp[start_secs*song_rate:(start_secs + duration_secs)*song_rate]
    display(Audio(data=s, rate=song_rate,autoplay=True))
    mythread =  threading.Thread(target=animate_images, args=(start_secs,width_secs, duration_secs))
    mythread.start()
    return None

v = interactive(play_music, start_secs=(0, 14), width_secs=(0.001,1.0), duration_secs=(1,13))
display(v)
mythread.join()
```

Comment: Bonus points if you can get it to work even when the thread hasn't finished yet!

Comment: Did you tried to use widgets.output? You can define an output in play_music() function and every time that updates, change the output to the new graph.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `ipywidgets.Audio` to observe the widget, but no success, anyway, here is a semi-functional code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from IPython.display import Audio
from ipywidgets import interactive, widgets, Output

import time

def note(frequency, length, amplitude=1, sample_rate=44100):
    time_points = np.linspace(0, length, length*sample_rate)
    data = np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*time_points)
    data = amplitude*data
    return data

song_rate = 22050
song_amp =  np.concatenate(
             (note(440.00, 1, 1.0, song_rate),  #A 
              note(493.88, 1, 0.9, song_rate),  #B 
              note(523.25, 1, 0.8, song_rate),  #C
              note(587.33, 1, 0.7, song_rate),  #D 
              note(659.25, 1, 0.6, song_rate),  #E
              note(698.46, 1, 0.5, song_rate),  #F
              note(783.99, 1, 0.4, song_rate),  #G
              ),             
             axis=-1)

animation_frames_per_secs = 1
output2 = Output()

def animate_images(start_secs, width_secs, duration_secs):
    for tick in range(duration_secs*animation_frames_per_secs):
        curr_time = start_secs + (tick*1.0/animation_frames_per_secs)
        make_image(curr_time, width_secs)
        time.sleep(1.0/animation_frames_per_secs)

def make_image(current_time, time_window):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 2))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    x = np.arange(int(current_time*song_rate),
                      int((current_time+time_window)*song_rate),
                      1)/song_rate
    y = song_amp[int(current_time*song_rate):int((current_time+time_window)*song_rate)]
    ax1.plot(x,y)
    output2.clear_output(wait=True)
    with output2:
        plt.show()
    
    plt.close()

def play_music(start_secs=0, width_secs=3.0/440, duration_secs=2):
    s = song_amp[start_secs*song_rate:(start_secs + duration_secs)*song_rate]
    audio = Audio(data=s, rate=song_rate,autoplay=False)
    display(audio)
    animate_images(start_secs,width_secs, duration_secs)
    return None

v = interactive(play_music, start_secs=(0, 14), width_secs=(0.001,1.0), duration_secs=(1,13))
display(v)
display(output2)
```